# Difference between "type", "instance", "class" and "object" concepts

Tags: terminology, supercollider

I am trying to understand the concept of classes and objects, and I came across to the words "type" and "instance". Does type mean exactly the same thing as class, and instance for object? Or is there a difference in between, such as a usage difference etc.?

Comment: These terms are not specific to supercollider. Please see this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_object-oriented_programming_terms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Quick Example**

A *class* is the design specs for a MacbookPro, an *instance* is your MacbookPro specifically.

A *type* is just a *class* that defines your *class*, so that we can look at a blueprint and ask if `design spec is MacbookProBlueprint`.  This is useful when we want meta-data about our classes (or other types). Think of a *type* as an Amazon.com entry, that would have lots of information about the MacbookPro such as processor speed and capabilities but not enough to actually build the object.

An *object* is your MacbookPro, or my car, or anything.  Everything is an object which has implications larger than the scope of this question, but is fundamental nonetheless.

Answer (score 0):

The SuperCollider book does a nice job of both summarizing programming concepts (particularly object oriented ones) and simultaneously demonstrating them in the SuperCollider language. See [here](http://supercolliderbook.net/) for more information. It is a great resource, and the website has all of the code in a downloadable archive.